# Multiple htaccess rewrite conditions and rules?

Tags: .htaccess

Having some issues when adding a new condition and rule to my htaccess file. We are needing to redirect traffic from a specific referral domain. Existing htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~bayour8/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /~bayour8/public/404.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~bayour8/index.php [L]
#suPHP_ConfigPath /home/bayour8/public_html
</IfModule>
```

I need to add something like this but it never processes it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domainx.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?first-page.html$ http://www.domainy.com/pages/pagename/ [L]
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks fine to me. Why do you claim that it does not get "processed"?

Comment: When I do tests from domainx via links posted on domainx to domainy, I am never taken to the url

Comment: Sorry, it is still unclear after that comment what your actual situation is. What _exact_ URL do you request? How does your current, _full_ `.htaccess` style file look like and what are the configurations of the two http hosts involved?

Comment: The full current file is posted above. After the sentence "existing htaccess looks like this". And I need to add the two lines mentioned after (with actual domain names). We're experiencing issues with people from a malicious entity linking to us and sending malicious traffic to us. We want to redirect them to a legal disclaimer page. So any links to our site from their site that are clicked on would be taken to the disclaimer page.